# How to use window.crypto.subtle in vscode webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VSCode Webview, `window.crypto.subtle` not working.

The possible reason is (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle)):

```
This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS)
```

And in VSCode Webview, the `window.location.protocal` is `data:`

[image]

So, it has a polyfill to resolve this?

PS: I have tried some lib(eg [webcrypto-liner](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner), [webcrypto-shim](https://github.com/vibornoff/webcrypto-shim)), none of them working.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your exact same case but I was facing a similar issue. I wanted to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID, which has the same restriction

```
This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS)
```

I didn't realize it because was accessing a remote server by IP (protocol HTTP), and then realized it testing exposing my own localhost port with ngrok (which hosts over HTTP/HTTPS) and it worked successfully only on HTTPS hosted link.

Hope this helps! :)